# What could cause an onUse package and an export to not be defined during a package test?

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js, meteor-packages

package.js:

```
onUse
  api.imply('launch-screen', 'client')

onTest
  api.use('jamielob:reloader', 'client')
```

reloader.js:

```
LaunchScreen.hold();
```

reloader-tests.js

```
console.log(Reloader);
```

`LaunchScreen` is exported by the `launch-screen` package.

When I run the test (`meteor test-packages ./ --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`), I get this in the browser console:

```
reloader.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: LaunchScreen is not defined
```

Full repo:

https://github.com/lorensr/reloader

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bug in build system – use `api.use` instead of `api.imply` for all `onUse`